# Create a portal_user_catalog and have it used (Plone)

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm creating a fork of my Plone site (which has not been forked for a long time). This site has a special catalog object for user profiles (a special Archetypes-based object type) which is called `portal_user_catalog`:

```
$ bin/instance debug
>>> portal = app.Plone
>>> print [d for d in portal.objectMap() if d['meta_type'] == 'Plone Catalog Tool']
[{'meta_type': 'Plone Catalog Tool', 'id': 'portal_catalog'},
 {'meta_type': 'Plone Catalog Tool', 'id': 'portal_user_catalog'}]
```

This looks reasonable because the user profiles don't have most of the indexes of the "normal" objects, but have a small set of own indexes.

Since I found no way how to create this object from scratch, I exported it from the old site (as `portal_user_catalog.zexp`) and imported it in the new site.  This seemed to work, but I can't add objects to the imported catalog, not even by explicitly calling the `catalog_object` method.  Instead, the user profiles are added to the standard `portal_catalog`.

Now I found a module in my product which seems to serve the purpose (`Products/myproduct/exportimport/catalog.py`):

```
"""Catalog tool setup handlers.

$Id: catalog.py 77004 2007-06-24 08:57:54Z yuppie $
"""

from Products.GenericSetup.utils import exportObjects
from Products.GenericSetup.utils import importObjects

from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

from zope.component import queryMultiAdapter
from Products.GenericSetup.interfaces import IBody

def importCatalogTool(context):
    """Import catalog tool.
    """
    site = context.getSite()
    obj = getToolByName(site, 'portal_user_catalog')
    parent_path=''

    if obj and not obj():
        importer = queryMultiAdapter((obj, context), IBody)
        path = '%s%s' % (parent_path, obj.getId().replace(' ', '_'))
        __traceback_info__ = path
        print [importer]
        if importer:
            print importer.name
            if importer.name:
                path = '%s%s' % (parent_path, 'usercatalog')
                print path

            filename = '%s%s' % (path, importer.suffix)
            print filename
            body = context.readDataFile(filename)
            if body is not None:
                importer.filename = filename # for error reporting
                importer.body = body

        if getattr(obj, 'objectValues', False):
            for sub in obj.objectValues():
                importObjects(sub, path+'/', context)

def exportCatalogTool(context):
    """Export catalog tool.
    """
    site = context.getSite()
    obj = getToolByName(site, 'portal_user_catalog', None)
    if tool is None:
        logger = context.getLogger('catalog')
        logger.info('Nothing to export.')
        return

    parent_path=''

    exporter = queryMultiAdapter((obj, context), IBody)
    path = '%s%s' % (parent_path, obj.getId().replace(' ', '_'))
    if exporter:
        if exporter.name:
            path = '%s%s' % (parent_path, 'usercatalog')
        filename = '%s%s' % (path, exporter.suffix)
        body = exporter.body
        if body is not None:
            context.writeDataFile(filename, body, exporter.mime_type)

    if getattr(obj, 'objectValues', False):
        for sub in obj.objectValues():
            exportObjects(sub, path+'/', context)
```

I tried to use it, but I have no idea how it is supposed to be done;
I can't call it TTW (should I try to publish the methods?!).
I tried it in a `debug` session:

```
$ bin/instance debug
>>> portal = app.Plone
>>> from Products.myproduct.exportimport.catalog import exportCatalogTool
>>> exportCatalogTool(portal)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../Products/myproduct/exportimport/catalog.py", line 58, in exportCatalogTool
    site = context.getSite()
AttributeError: getSite
```

So, if this is the way to go, it looks like I need a "real" context.

**Update:** To get this context, I tried an `External Method`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Products.myproduct.exportimport.catalog import exportCatalogTool
from pdb import set_trace

def p(dt, dd):
    print '%-16s%s' % (dt+':', dd)

def main(self):
    """
    Export the portal_user_catalog
    """
    g = globals()
    print '#' * 79
    for a in ('__package__', '__module__'):
        if a in g:
            p(a, g[a])
    p('self', self)
    set_trace()
    exportCatalogTool(self)
```

However, wenn I called it, I got the same `<PloneSite at /Plone>` object as the argument to the `main` function, which didn't have the `getSite` attribute.  Perhaps my site doesn't call such External Methods correctly?

Or would I need to mention this module somehow in my `configure.zcml`, but how?  I searched my directory tree (especially below `Products/myproduct/profiles`) for `exportimport`, the module name, and several other strings, but I couldn't find anything; perhaps there has been an integration once but was broken ...

So how do I make this `portal_user_catalog` work?
Thank you!

**Update:** Another `debug` session suggests the source of the problem to be some `transaction` matter:

```
>>> portal = app.Plone
>>> puc = portal.portal_user_catalog
>>> puc._catalog()
[]
>>> profiles_folder = portal.some_folder_with_profiles
>>> for o in profiles_folder.objectValues():
...     puc.catalog_object(o)
...
>>> puc._catalog()
[<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0x69ff8d8>, ...]
```

This population of the `portal_user_catalog` doesn't persist; after termination of the `debug` session and starting `fg`, the brains are gone.

Comment: The `getSite` error is probably related to the call of the method from the `instance debug" environment

Comment: @keul: I tried an `External Method` (and updated the question), which sadly didn't work ... I'm confused. Shouldn't I get a context (including a `REQUEST`) when calling an `External Method`?

Comment: In a debug session you need to commit your changes. `transaction.commit()`

Comment: Ok, so this is a characteristic of the `debug` session; good to know.! However, this way I found out my catalog can take the values, and improved my `processNewUser` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was indeed related with transactions.
I had

```
import transaction
...
class Browser(BrowserView):
    ...
    def processNewUser(self):
        ....
        transaction.commit()
```

before, but apparently this was not good enough (and/or perhaps not done correctly).

Now I start the transaction explicitly with `transaction.begin()`, save intermediate results with `transaction.savepoint()`, abort the transaction explicitly with `transaction.abort()` in case of errors (`try` / `except`), and have exactly one `transaction.commit()` at the end, in the case of success. Everything seems to work.

Of course, Plone still doesn't take this non-standard catalog into account; when I "clear and rebuild" it, it is empty afterwards. But for my application it works well enough.

Comment: shouldn't you register your catalog in archetype_tool? Example: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/catalog.html#archetype-tool-catalog-map

Comment: @Yuri: Of course you are right - thank you! Looking closer, a former colleague had indeed written such a class - leaving out some important parts - but didn't register it anywhere in the `xml` files ... I always wondered! I'll recitify this.